# Setting Publish Location of project using MSBuild in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have a need for a PowerShell script that I can run to build a visual studio project, however I can't find any MS Build parameters that I can pass that allow me to set the publish location of a build. Is this possible?

Comment: do you want to perform a normal build or something like a file-system publish of a web project?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. A publish of a web project.